# event.target vs event.relatedTarget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the difference between event.target and event.relatedTarget. The following is a code chunk from drag and drop activity.

```html
  ondragleave: function (event) {
    // remove the drop feedback style
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
    event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out';

  }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget

Comment: Or explicitly for `dragleave`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragleave

Comment: _want to know the difference between event.target and event.relatedTarget._ - so what is your question?

Answer (score 15):

The `relatedTarget` event target is used by some events to specify a secondary target. On the other hand, target will be used by most DOM events to specify the primary target of an event.

For instance, during `focus` events, `target` will be the element gaining focus, and relatedTarget will be the element losing focus.

You can check out an exhaustive list of DOM events that specify a relatedTarget here: [MouseEvent.relatedTarget.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget)

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062841/what-is-the-difference-between-e-target-and-e-relatedtarget)

So judging from the above explanation we can say that

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

In this example, when you hover inside the inner div, then in the handler:

- `event.target` refers to the `.inner` element (this gives you the element
  where the event originated)
- `event.relatedTarget` refers to the `.outer` element (this gives you the element that receives the focus first and the loose the focus to other element)

you can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uTe99/) for better understanding

---

Now in your own scenario

```
ondragleave: function (event) {
    /*when the dragged element leaves the drop target, remove the 
    .drop-target class from the current focused element*/
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
    
    /*remove the .can-drop class from the element that looses focus 
    to the current focused element and changed the text to Dragged Out*/
    event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out';

  }
```

Thanks.