# What is the difference between e.target and e.relatedTarget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When using jQuery `on` `e.target` gives me the element which triggered the even but when using Bootstrap modal I access the triggering element via `e.relatedTarget`. I would like to understand how they differ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `relatedTarget` event target is used by some events to specify a secondary target and [isn't specific to jQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets). On the other hand, `target` will be used by most DOM events to specify the primary target of an event.

For instance, during `focus` events, `target` will be the element gaining focus, and `relatedTarget` will be the [element losing focus](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#interface-focusevent).

You can check out an exhaustive list of DOM events that specify a *relatedTarget* here: [MouseEvent.relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget).